# Vueform Axios Response Object

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt3

I am using `Vueform` in my `Nuxt3` app.

As `Vueform` uses `Axios` to send requests, how to capture the `Axios response object`?

Answer (score 0):

This has been effectively answered by the vueform maintainer at -

https://github.com/vueform/vueform/discussions/74

By following that discussion, I have managed to capture the response.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)